# Adding decimal formatting to Knockout number data bindings

Tags: knockout.js

I am using knockout to populate number values inside a table:

HTML:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: commision">
             <tr>
                 <td>
                    <span>R </span><span data-bind="text: Amount"></span>
                 </td>
             </tr>...
</tbody>
```

Knockout.js part pertaining to amount and commision

```
 var vm = {
            commision: ko.observable(),
            futurecommision: ko.observable(),
            commisionpaid: ko.observable(),
            totals: ko.observable(),
            commisionPaid: ko.observable(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(ko.mapping.fromJS({
                Date: null,
                Amount: 0
            }))),
...
```

Now how do i show the number being populated in decimal fomat, say .00 ?
eg. 10.00

Currently it is only showing the number, eg 10

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could look into writing a custom extender to handle this.

A basic extender is something like:

```
ko.extenders.numeric = function(target, precision) {
    var result = ko.computed({
        read: function() {
            return target().toFixed(precision); 
        },
        write: target 
    });

    result.raw = target;
    return result;
};
```

This is then used on your observables like:

```
var commissionPaid = ko.observable(whatever your value is).extend({numeric: 2});
```

Comment: +1 works like a charm http://jsfiddle.net/m6ZKZ/ note however that dependentObservable is deprecated, use ko.computed() instead

Comment: thank you Thewads and Thank you xec, appreciate the fiddle. Any way I can add Digit Grouping: ie 10 000.00, 100 000.00, 1 000 000.00 etc ?

Comment: I dont see why not, would just have to modify the above code to probably use regex to split the value

Comment: @DextrousDave have a look at this fiddle I knocked up, should give you a starter for your second question http://jsfiddle.net/m6ZKZ/1/

Comment: thank you, but you need to give me some more help here, this is greek to me. I did however find another nice solution to this original problem but without Digit grouping: http://jsfiddle.net/rRaHm/2/

Comment: Great example -- I'm using this as the starting point for what I need. I'm wondering what result.raw is for -- something you use elsewhere?

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at this KO Money Extender:

http://jsfiddle.net/digitalbush/R6MPU/

```
(function(){
    var format = function(value) {
        toks = value.toFixed(2).replace('-', '').split('.');
        var display = '$' + $.map(toks[0].split('').reverse(), function(elm, i) {
            return [(i % 3 === 0 && i > 0 ? ',' : ''), elm];
        }).reverse().join('') + '.' + toks[1];

        return value < 0 ? '-' + display : display;
    };

ko.subscribable.fn.money = function() {
    var target = this;

    var writeTarget = function(value) {
        var stripped=value
            .replace(/[^0-9.-]/g, '');

        target(parseFloat(stripped));
    };

    var result = ko.computed({
        read: function() {
            return target();
        },
        write: writeTarget
    });

    result.formatted = ko.computed({
        read: function() {
            return format(target());
        },
        write: writeTarget
    });

    result.isNegative = ko.computed(function(){
        return target()<0;
    });

    return result;
};
})();

//Wire it up
$(function() {
    var viewModel = {
        Cash: ko.observable(-1234.56).money(),
        Check: ko.observable(2000).money(),
        showJSON: function() {
            alert(ko.toJSON(viewModel));
        }
    };


    viewModel.Total = ko.computed(function() {
        return this.Cash() + this.Check();
    }, viewModel).money();
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

Comment: @David
Excellent work. I was looking for this fix for writable money value variables. 

I have made two changes on top of what you have done :
1. When value changes in input field, it immediately tries to format the value i.e. before user finish typing, it formats the value and update in input field which is not desirable. Hence, I used Ratelimit to propogate changes after delay 

self.Variable= ko.observable().extend({ rateLimit: 2000 }).money()

2. Also, in input field if value is removed it was showing NaN error message. To handle that I put check for IsNaN in format function

Comment: great! any idea how to internationalize this function? could be, using an extender makes this easier?