# Knockout updating decimal places from observable

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have an observable item and I am trying to apply user driven formatting on that observable.  I have an integer input box where a user can select how many decimal places, 0-6.  I am trying to update the observable to apply decimal places based on the selection in that input box.

I first tried a computed value, which did not work.  Returned an error that 'toFixed' was not a function.

```
this.formattedResult = ko.computed(function () {
    var newValue = self.decimalValue();
    var precision = self.decimalPlaces();
    return newValue.toFixed(precision);
});
```

I then tried adding a binding handler, which results in 'uncaught object' on the 'toFixed'

```
ko.bindingHandlers.numericText = {
update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    var value = new String(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()).toString());
    var precision = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().precision);
    var formattedValue = value.toFixed(precision);

    ko.bindingHandlers.text.update(element, function () { return formattedValue; });
},
defaultPrecision: 1
};
```

Then I tried extending numeric with a numericText, which also results in a 'uncaught object' error on the 'toFixed'.

```
ko.extenders.numeric = function (target, precision) {
if (precision() != null) {
    var precisionValue = target();
    console.log(precisionValue);
    var precisionDecimal = precisionValue.toFixed(2);
    console.log(precisionDecimal);
    var result = ko.dependentObservable({
        read: function () {
            return target().toFixed(precision());
        },
        write: target
    });

    result.raw = target;
    return result;
}
else
    return target;
};
```

The binding on the HTML elements were all updated to take these changes into account but they did not work.  I also tried just simply adding 'toFixed' to the data binding in the HTML and that also did not work.

I found these similar questions but the solutions are not working for me.

[Format knockout observable with commas and/or decimal places within html data binding, NOT in viewmodel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19914330/format-knockout-observable-with-commas-and-or-decimal-places-within-html-data-bi)

[Formatting rules for numbers in KnockoutJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704268/formatting-rules-for-numbers-in-knockoutjs)

[Adding decimal formatting to Knockout number data bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009493/adding-decimal-formatting-to-knockout-number-data-bindings)

This is a very frustrating problem as I thought it would be really simple to add decimal places in a computed function.  What am I doing wrong?

I'm not sure if it matters but I am using knockout 3.1

Edit:

I also tried just simply adding 'toFixed' to the data-binding but that also results in an uncaught object.

```
<p data-bind="text: decimalValue().toFixed(2)"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't end up solving my problem in the way that I had anticipated but I modified the computed column to force the decimal to a float and then added the decimals to that float value.

The final function looks like this:

```
this.formattedResult = ko.computed(function () {
    var newValue = parseFloat(self.decimalValue());
    var precision = self.decimalPlaces();
    return newValue.toFixed(precision);
});
```

I don't know why this works but the other does not?  Maybe when I assign the value to newValue I'm just assigning an observable to it and the observable doesn't know how to handle toFixed()?  Doesn't explain all of the other problems but at least this is fixed for me.

Comment: because `toFixed` is function of `Number` object, all your errors from various attempts came from calling `toFixed` on a `String` type object :-)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the following JavaScript Number constructor which will return NaN if the number is invalid.

```
this.formattedResult = ko.computed(function () {
// call the number constructor. newValue is now a number or NaN 
//we choose a default value as well.
     var newValue = isNaN(self.decimalValue()) ? 0 :  
Number(self.decimalValue()); 
// call the number constructor again
     var precision = isNaN(self.decimalPlaces()) ? 0 :  Number(self.decimalPlaces()); 
     return newValue.toFixed(precision);
 });
```